# Retrieve Header Background Image with AJAX

Tags: ajax, post-thumbnails

The featured image (for posts & pages) in my theme is a header background image.
Actually each featured image is retrieved by the following **function** in `functions.php` :

```
function mytheme_header_style() {
    // Declare $post global if used outside of the loop.
    $post = get_post();
    // Check if post is object otherwise we're not in singular post.
    if (!is_object($post)) {
        return;
    }
    // If Object
    $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '');
    // Add inline style to the backgroung header image.
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $custom_header_style = '
            .intro-header {
                background-image: url( ' . $backgroundImg[0] . ' );
            }
        ';
    } else {
        $custom_header_style = '
            .intro-header {
                background-image: url( ' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/components/header/images/default-hero.jpg' . ' );
            }
        ';
    }
    wp_add_inline_style( 'mytheme-main-style', $custom_header_style );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_header_style' );
```

This background image is responsive and manipulated by a **jQuery function** in a separated `hero.js` file to always be fullscreen on any device/screen size like so :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // Defining a function to set size for #masthead 
    function fullscreen() {
        jQuery('#masthead').css({
            width: jQuery(window).width(),
            height: jQuery(window).height()
        });
    }

    fullscreen();

    // Run the function in case of window resize
    jQuery(window).resize(function () {
        fullscreen();
    });

});
```

The **HTML** structure of `header.php` makes this featured background header image separated from the main content like so :

```
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <nav>...</nav>
     <!-- Page Header -->
     <?php
     if (is_404()) {
         get_template_part('components/header/bg', '404');
     } elseif (is_search()) {
         get_template_part('components/header/bg', 'search');
     } else {
         get_template_part('components/header/bg', 'header'); // mytheme_header_style() is called here
     }
     ?>
    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div id="content">...</div>
  </div>//#page
  <footer>...</footer>
</body>
```

**I'm trying the following**
**1-** localize `hero.js`

```
function mytheme_header_style_script() {

        // Adding custom javascript header style file to theme.
        wp_enqueue_script('mytheme-hero', get_theme_file_uri() . '/assets/js/hero.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_localize_script('mytheme-hero', 'hero_ajax', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_header_style_script');
```

**2-** add wp_ajax action to `mytheme_header_style()` function

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_header_style' );
add_action('wp_ajax_heroajax', 'mytheme_header_style');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_heroajax', 'mytheme_header_style');
```

**3-** Then I've changed the `hero.js` like so :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: hero_ajax.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action : 'heroajax'
        },
        // callback handler that will be called on success
        // Defining a function to set size for #masthead
        success: function fullscreen(imageUrl, textStatus, jqXHR){
            // log a message to the console
            console.log("Hooray, it worked! Load The Image Here");
                $('#masthead').css({
                    width: $(window).width(),
                    height: $(window).height()
                });
                $('#masthead').css('background-image', 'url(' + DefaultimageUrl + ')');
        },
        // callback handler that will be called on error
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            DefaultimageUrl = 'path/to/default/image.jpg';                        
            // log the error to the console
            console.log(
                "Load Default Image here! The following error occured: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
            $('#masthead').css('background-image', 'url(' + DefaultimageUrl + ')');
        }
    });

    fullscreen();

    // Run the function in case of window resize
    $(window).resize(function () {
        fullscreen();
    });

});
```

This is not working, the featured background header image is no longer full screen and the JS debugger is highlighting **`$.ajax`** and says **Paused on Exception**  and I'm not getting any message in the console.
What I'm doing wrong ?
Much appreciate your help, thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than i thought.
After a lot of reading and trying I've finally got it !
This is the answer with explications if it can help someone.
**1-** In **`functions.php`**  localize `hero.js`

```
function mytheme_header_script() {

    // Adding custom javascript file to handle the header image.
    wp_enqueue_script('mytheme-hero', get_theme_file_uri() . '/assets/js/hero.js', array('jquery'), '', true); // I'm putting the script in the footer

    // Declare $post global if used outside of the loop.
    $post = get_post();

    // Retrieve the featured image by using wp_get_attachment_image_src
    // and include the id of the post as a parameter for get_post_thumbnail_id (which we retrieve using $post->id)
    $heroImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '');

    // This is an array of values that we will use each by it's key in hero.js script file
    $heroSettings = array (
        'featured_image'     => $heroImg[0], // Retrieve the featured image and display it if set
        'default_image'      => get_template_directory_uri() . '/components/header/images/default-hero.jpg', // Display the default image if no featured image is set
        'has_post_thumbnail' => has_post_thumbnail(), // To use the function in js
        'ajaxurl'            => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), // The URL to admin-ajax.php
        'success'            => 'Hooray, it worked! The featured image is loaded', // Print this message in the console if the featured image is displayed
        'default'            => 'The default image is loaded' // Print this message in the console if the default image is displayed
    );
    // Now use the wp_localize_script function
    // Set the same $handle as the script to localize it
    // hero-set is the name of the js variable that will contain the data
    // $heroSettings is the array of data to retrieve in js by hero_set
    wp_localize_script('mytheme-hero', 'hero_set', $heroSettings);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_header_script');
```

**2-** Still the same :)

**3-** **`hero.js`** became this

```
(function($) {

    // Define the fullscreen function
    fullscreen();

    // Tell the fullscreen function what to do using ajax
    function fullscreen() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', // use $_POST method to submit the data
            url: hero_set.ajaxurl, // submit the data to admin-ajax.php
            data: {
                action : 'mytheme_header_style'
                // process mytheme_header_style function by the requested data action
            },
            // use beforeSend so the background header image is retrieved and displayed
            // wright away before anything else to speed the page load
            beforeSend : function(){
                // if a featured image is set
                if (hero_set.has_post_thumbnail){
                    // log the success message to the console
                    console.log(hero_set.success);
                    $('#masthead').css({
                        'background-image': 'url(' + hero_set.featured_image + ')',
                        width: $(window).width(),
                        height: $(window).height()
                    });
                } else {
                    // if no featured image is set
                    // log the default message to the console
                    console.log(hero_set.default);
                    $('#masthead').css({
                        'background-image': 'url(' + hero_set.default_image + ')',
                        width: $(window).width(),
                        height: $(window).height()
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Run the function in case of window resize.
    $(window).resize(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fullscreen();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

That's all folks, hope it will help someone.
SYA